# How does the trace operator resolve the "restriction to the boundary" issue in Sobolev spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, trace

In section 5.5 of Evans PDE book he introduces the trace operator. He states the motivation behind this operator being that generally $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$ is not continuous or is only defined a.e. in $U$. Consequently, $\partial U$ may have Lebesgue measure zero and hence, as Evans puts it, there is no direct meaning we can give to the expression "$u$ restricted to $\partial U$".

Even before introducing trace class operators, how do the above two issues make the expression "$u$ restricted to $\partial U$" undefined?

The trace theorem states that if $U$ is bounded and $\partial U \in C^1$, then there exists a bounded linear operator
$$T: W^{1,p}(U) \rightarrow L^p(\partial U)$$
such that
$$Tu = u\vert_{\partial U}, \quad u \in W^{1,p}(U) \cap C(\overline{U})\tag{1}$$
and
$$\|Tu\|_{L^p(\partial U)} \leq C\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(U)}. \tag{2}$$

Isn't (2) simply stating that $T$ is bounded? But this is already assumed as a hypothesis in the theorem. Secondly, how does the trace operator solve the "restriction to the boundary" problem exactly described by Evans, it seems (1) is trivially restricting $u$ to the boundary, so what's different?

Comment: The word 'undefined' sounds a bit like 'it is defined and the definition is somehow invalidated'. That's not the case. If you want to define the restriction of a function to a subset of measure $0$ and the function cannot be distinguished from one you get if you replace it on (any) set of measure $0$, you have an issue with the restriction being well defined. You can just define it as $=0$ on $\partial U$ and also as $=1$ without changing the original map in a way you could detect. Now which value do you take for the trace? $0$ or $1$?

Comment: Also the hypothesis of the theorem does not include the boundedness of $T$, that part of the conclusion ("then there exists..."). And (1) is only true for continuous functions. For a continuous function, it is clear how to define the trace.

Comment: @Thomas Ah yes that was a careless mistake on my part. I see the power of the theorem now, it guarantees the existence/uniqueness of a bounded (and hence continuous) restriction to the boundary. However what is still unclear is how does the trace choose the "right" set of measure 0 on the boundary? For example in the context of PDEs, how does it guarantee the image of $T$ is the boundary condition?

Comment: The whole boundary has measure $0$, there is no subset to choose. In the context of a boundary value problem the boundary values are defined in a similar manner by restricting some $g$ which is defined on $U$ to $\partial U$. A solution $f$ attains these boundary values if the trace of $f-g$ is zero.

Comment: @Thomas Subset is the wrong word sorry, I meant within the equivalence class of functions with measure zero how does the trace operator choose the correct one?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. The trace operator is defined on the set of continuous functions in an unambiguous way, and that space is dense in $W^{1,p}$. By continuity, it has a unique extension. This is what you get. (Of course you could change the continuous function on a set of measure $0$, but it would still have a continuos representative)

Comment: @Thomas Apologies if I'm being confusing, I will try to be more clear. So the continuity of the trace operator is what allows us to select the "correct" set of measure zero on the boundary? For example, say in Poisson's equation we have the boundary condition $u = g$ and in another case $u = h$. Both are of measure zero since it is the same geometry and both correspond to the same PDE, so how does the trace operator allow us to select the boundary condition we want?

Comment: No. Again: the boundary has measure $0$. There is no set of measure $0$ to select, you want to define the map on the boundary. A choice is made by defining the map $T$ on a set where the definition is straightforward (maps with continuous boundary values) and by extending by continuity. If $f$ and $g$ are different choices for boundary values of continuous functions, then they will be the restrictions of different maps (with continuous representatives).

Comment: @Thomas I think I got it now, thank you for all your help and patience!